# I am getting out of memory errors while fetching data from postgresql server in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, airflow

I have airflow installed on a linux machine and inside airflow container I have made setting of spark for data transformation and processing data but when I try pulling data from postgresql I get out of memory error.
Running spark in local mode inside airflow container.

Here is code I am using:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("data pull") \
        .config("spark.executor.cores","4") \
        .config("spark.executor.memory","32g") \
        .config("spark.driver.memory","16g") \
        .getOrCreate()

query = "select  c1,c2,c3 from t1 where date > '2023-06-01'"

df = spark.read() \
     .format("jdbc") \
     .option("url",url) \
     .option("query",query) \
     .options(**properties) \
     .load()

df.show()
```

Comment: You can do multiple solutions to solve this issue.
- Try to reduce the amount of data pulled from the database. Try to use a filter instead of getting all the data.
- Try to use partition the data in the database based on columns.
- Check if VM running Airflow has enough memory for the Spark executor.
- Use Clusters if the data is too big and you need to optimize servers.
-Try to increase the server configurations and enable the swap spaces.

Comment: The am already using date column to provide the selective data. Table is already paritioned on date column in Postgresql DB or Do you mean Partitions in spark config while loading data?
And I am running airflow on docker-compose and inside airflow container I have defined environment variables for JAVA and spark to run spark stuff in .py files. 
How to check the memory given to spark executor if spark is being run on local mode?
Can clusters be made if spark is being used in airflow container? 
current linux server where I have this all is having enough memory 128GB and CPUs 32 available

Comment: Try to pull specific date data, monitor stages on Spark UI and check read records count. If it works then try to read more date data.